# when app is offline, store the entered in local cache and then sync with firebase real time database when app is back online

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, synchronization, local-storage

I made an app on android studio for calculating finance and am using firebase realtime database for storing entered data. When the user loses internet connectivity, the data they enter, when offline, should be stored in the device's local cache and then pushed to firebase database when the user is back online. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it like this:

Java: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

Kotlin: `Firebase.database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)`

But I highly recommend you to read this [doc page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) for more options.